# Using an ORM like DevForce, do you recommend isolating it from the applications using a service bus or something?

Tags: architecture, orm, servicebus, devforce

We are in the process of choosing a way to isolate our .NET client applications from a SQLServer database and we are leaning toward the DevForce ORM.

This ORM is used for distributed applications and provides its own application server for handling clients requests.

However, I feel that the client applications would be too tightly coupled to the ORM so I thought of using a service bus along with it (NServiceBus) or even a request/response service layer like Agatha.

Specifically, since we have .NET 2 applications and DevForce supports .NET4 we might have to do an isolation layer anyway...

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that shielding clients from that implementation is a good idea, but my first thought would have been interfaces rather than a service bus.

Comment: I thought of using interfaces as well, however I'm not sure if that would allow for .NET 2 clients to be used with the ORM... That's why I am advocating a service bus or some sort.